# Transiting in Kathmandu in aftermath of earthquake

Tags: nepal, event-based-effects, natural-disasters

I am due to depart in 9 days with a friend for a trip centred in Nepal, with shorter trips to Bhutan and Mumbai.  The aftermath of the weekend's earthquake means this is no longer viable, and the British government are advising against all but essential travel to the country.  Fortunately my travel insurance policy has allowed me to rearrange nearly all of the holiday to avoid Nepal.

The one exception is that the night of the 16 May where I cannot see an alternative but to spend about 24 hours in Kathmandu, arriving by plane that morning and departing the next morning by plane.  Can anyone suggest how I can find out how safe Kathmandu currently is, and how feasible it might be to spend a night there?

Comment: Conditions at the airport now are pretty congested but things may change (for the better) before your departure. Prepare for last minute changes.

Comment: There are some camps around Kathmandu these days (I have some friends there helping them), but we expect them to be moved and hopefully people will be given better alternative stay by that time.  Airport is already being used. I'd be surprised things aren't better by May 16.

Comment: @AyeshK - Do you know whether there hotels still standing and open to business?  Does the city have running water and electricity?

Comment: Are you asking about safe as in from crime or safe as in from collapsing buildings?

Comment: I don't think the situation is good enough for a tourist to be there. We are sending them water, food, and medicine. It's really unfortunate there. Everyone is already helping them, so I think you'll be able to make it after two days. Here's our center: http://i.imgur.com/mYulYWK.jpg

Comment: Anything we say right now is going to be subject to change between now and nine days time. Read the news, check government travel advisories, and you will know as much as we do.

Comment: Understood, @DJClayworth. But I need to make a decision in the next day or two on whether to spend that night in Kathmandu, and the only alternative leaves me significantly out of pocket (in way my insurance won't cover).

Comment: If you can change your plans without costing money, I would actually do that instead of guessing how good it would be in two weeks. There isn't even electricity or road access to reach remote places. One night in the airport would not be bad I guess, but almost certainly, you won't be able to visit the city (Kathmandu or Phokra).

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining why you cannot find an alternative to a connection in Kathmandu.  Surely your final destination, whatever it is, has flights from other places?  Why can't you just change to a flight that connects somewhere else instead?  Odds are your airline will be happy to facilitate that, as they are likely to have trouble serving Kathmandu themselves.

Comment: Why does your insurance not cover this? Cancellation insurance usually pays out in the case of an issued travel advisory, and most governments have issued those.

Comment: @NateEldredge - The circumstances are quite complicated because three people are involved, all with slightly different itineraries and different travel insurance policies, each of whom have a different idea of what's a valid alteration; we're arriving from Bhutan, and there are only a tiny number of flights out of the country and few remaining seats; one of the party has a non-negotiable requirement to be back in London first thing Monday morning; and the three airlines involved all consider Kathmandu open for business as normal and are not changing their flights.

Comment: Frankly, I find your holier-than-thou attitude pretty offensive, @Ideogram.  Not that it's any of your business, but I've made a substantial donation that will hopefully provide material benefit to those affected, in a way that vacuous words of sympathy that will never be read by those affected never will.

Comment: @Richard Smith  I'm sorry, I did not mean to sound offending. My words were inappropiate. Truth be sad, it's what happens if you first watch the news (featuring the Eearthquake) and then browse Stackexchange. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

According to this (I'm sorry: *Dutch*) newspaper article (http://www.trouw.nl/tr/nl/4496/Buitenland/article/detail/3984619/2015/04/28/Hulp-stokt-in-logistieke-nachtmerrie.dhtml) (in the last paragraph), the rain season is about to start in a coouple of weeks over there, making things even worse for the Nepali. It might also make it worse for you. I can't tell, but you might want to add this factor to your equation.